# Route to another page/component from modal in Angular and Ng bootstrap

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, ng-bootstrap

I am trying to navigate from the modal dialog to another page however it does not navigate but only changes the url location.

A very basic stackblitz is here https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-j4rahu-oj8pcn
As you can see the edit component is never navigated to.

EDIT: Sorry, I thought I had the blitz forked but it was wrong link. Apologies and now I have the new blitz. It has the router module

EDIT: to reproduce the issue. click LaunchModal => click close. Should navigate to edit component.

Comment: Your question is quite misleading. What we have to do to reproduce the issue?

Comment: There is no router file in the Stackblitz

Comment: @Kenny, I now have edited sorry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ahh!!!

You have mention `<router-outlet></router-outlet>` in your `app.component.html` file

I replaced

```
<ngbd-modal-component></ngbd-modal-component>
```

With

```
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

And it started working

As `<router-outlet>` handles routes and renders components specified in `Routes` array

More information https://angular.io/api/router/RouterOutlet

Comment: Kenny,  it did solve the issue here, but I have a different problem then.
I have a <router-outlet> in the appcomponent. The app component directs call to my dashboard component. The dashboard component has 
```` <div *ngFor="let item of items">
<app-item [id]="item.id"> </app-item>````

My app-item component has the following html
````<div class="card">
...
<button (click)="open(content)" >
<ng-template #content let-modal>
...
</ng-template>
````
Where should router outlet come in this situation. 
Thanks.

Comment: Ok, I just did it before the template and it is working fine

Comment: Didn't understand the problem. Though It is a different problem, you can raise a another question or edit this question with proper explanation and example would be great.